# Arrows on connections in schematics

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

Im using eagle, and was wondering how i'd produce arrows like this:
[image: arrows in schematic]

Is there a specific name for these? That show connections between many schematics.

Comment: I call them I/O lines, but don't know if that's common. The line like CE is an output for this circuit (but will be an input on another circuit), and the MISO for example is an input for this circuit. There's also a line with two arrows, on both sides one, and that's input/output. But once again, these might not be common names.

Comment: Those are called "ports" in Altium, possibly the same terminology in other CAD software.

Comment: Eagle doesn't have this as far as I know. It's only connected through net names. You can place net labels above the wires to show it.

Comment: Those arrows are labels or net names. They assign a name to the net a.k.a. wire. This way you don't have to actually draw wires between parts, you can simply drop labels on your devices pins/ports and avoid the spaghetti mess of wires. In kiCAD you have local and global labels. Local labels are for the current schematic sheet. Other schematics that are part of your project are on different sheets. You can bridge them using global labels.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**In Eagle**, right click on the *label* (or add one to the net first), choose properties and check the Xref box and click OK. I think the accurate name for these is Cross-References.

[image]

Comment: I was talking about using them on my own schematics. No changing them on the existing schematic as thats a PDF.

Comment: @Dean This is the correct answer. The Wire tool creates a Net. The Label tool adds a label to the Net. Going to the Properties, clicking Xref will turn the label into an arrow thingy. FWIW, I've always heard them called Off-Page Connectors.

Comment: @vicatcu Oh, why would you use a wire to make a net when there is a net tool right above the label tool? Also, this is a good answer, I have also always called them Off-Page connections.

Comment: @vicatcu Sorry, I didn't quite understand the instruction correctly, its now clear. Thanks for adding the image embedded.kyle.

Comment: @embedded.kyle I agree with Dean, using the Net tool is more appropriate

Comment: @vicatcu You're right. I'm used to working in Orcad in which case the Wire tool creates the nets. But in Eagle the Net tool is more appropriate. But it was the label tool he was having trouble understanding and it works the same for either oddly enough.

Comment: One more tip: When creating net labels, you can make them XREF by default by selecting the XREF mode, saving you the step of Properties->Xref checkbox. http://imgur.com/nNnGhKl

Comment: @MarkRenouf that's awesome, thanks for the tip! I always type CHANGE XREF ON in command line

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the NAME tool now . Just type: `name MY_NEW_NET_NAME_HERE` into the command box at any time then click twice on the net you want to rename. You can rename two nets to the same name doing this and they become logically the same NET. The label tool simply visibly shows what the underlying NET name is.